# A puzzle about using Esper ”group by“ + “sum”

Tags: batch-file, time, group-by, sum, esper

I create a epl like this：

```
`String epl = "select objId,sum(c1) from PmData.win:time_batch(3 sec) group by objId";`
```

it's very simple：export sum(c1) result every 3 seconds in the sliding window.

but when i runs the test, the result is not as my expected,it seems wrong: it exports objId that not exists in the sliding window.

Here is the result print:

select objId,sum(c1) from PmData.win:time_batch(3 sec) group by objId

2016-04-08 18:31:16

send event :PmData(objId=2, c1=0, time=0)

send event :PmData(objId=0, c1=8, time=0)

send event :PmData(objId=3, c1=7, time=0)

send event :PmData(objId=0, c1=3, time=0)

2016-04-08 18:31:19

events update result： {objId=0, sum(c1)=11}

events update result： {objId=2, sum(c1)=0}

events update result： {objId=3, sum(c1)=7}

----------------above is 1st window-----------------------------------

send event :PmData(objId=3, c1=5, time=0)

send event :PmData(objId=0, c1=2, time=0)

send event :PmData(objId=1, c1=1, time=0)

2016-04-08 18:31:22

events update result： {objId=0, sum(c1)=2}

events update result： {objId=1, sum(c1)=1}

**events update result： {objId=2, sum(c1)=null}**

events update result： {objId=3, sum(c1)=5}

----------------above is 2nd window-----------------------------------

send event :PmData(objId=3, c1=4, time=0)

send event :PmData(objId=0, c1=6, time=0)

send event :PmData(objId=0, c1=3, time=0)

2016-04-08 18:31:25
events update result： {objId=0, sum(c1)=9}

**events update result： {objId=1, sum(c1)=null}**

events update result： {objId=3, sum(c1)=4}

----------------above is 3rd window-----------------------------------

**why the 2nd windos export the objId=2 's? the 2nd sliding window has no event (objId=2).

but when i query like this:

`String epl = "select objId,sum(c1) from PmData.win:time_batch(3 sec)`

the result is ok.**

is anyone can answer?

and is it has a solution(without using "group_by")?

Answer (score 0):

As events get removed from data window(s), Esper outputs all changes to aggregations such as the "sum" aggregation according to which events enter and which events get removed. This is the same across all data windows including the non-sliding batching ones. So when a certain group goes away its sum will go to null meaning there are no more data points that make up the sum. If you added count(*) you would see it go to zero. Such output can be removed with "having sum(...) is not null" or by using context partitions.

Comment: ,@user3613754,thx very mach. I ask this question is that i got a problem, may you help me plz?  like the above example, i want calculate sum(c0),avg(c1), max(c2),min(c3), last event's c4, first event’s c5 group by objId in the sliding window.  i want calculate them just in one epl.   i try write like this:String epl = "select objId, sum(c0) as c0,avg(c1) as c1, max(c2) as c2 , min(c3) as c3, maxby(fmax(time, c4>=0)).c4 as c4, maxby(fmin(time, c5>=0)).c5 as c5 from Event.win:time_batch(5 sec) group by objId" . c0~c3 is ok, but the c4 or c5 always got  value from the removed sliding window.

Comment: ,@user3613754,but the c4 or c5 always got value from the removed sliding window. that's not i want. i want get c4,c5's value in the current sliding window.